# Can I call a function from flutter PWA using Javascript? if yes how?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

I'm currently trying to connect a JS code to my flutter web app. And then call a function from my flutter application in JS.

I'm thinking the problem is, flutter PWA is compiled to js (main.dart.js) and thus it's function names, and function bodies are lost. Am I right about this? Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the Dart team has you covered with an interop js package which lets you call JS from the Dart VM -> [package link](https://pub.dev/packages/js). If you're already using that and you're encounting an error with that - lemme know.

Comment: thanks! are the two functions connected? I mean if JS changes local variable 'a' , is 'a' also changed in Dart? if not, is there a way to connect the two?

Comment: it is an FFI (foreign function interface) therefore you would have to setup explicit setters in your JS code that also syncs the value inside of Dart